# Trouble in authorization with post request in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, post

I have a some problem with authorization in my app. I realize it through factory and controller, post method send request, but in response i have log from server, that values are wrong.
But if I change body of doLogin function to jQuery ajax method and don't use factory, all is OK. What is wrong with my Angular way?

My AngularJS Code

Form:

```
<form ng-submit="doLogin(credentials)">
  <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Username</span>
      <input type="text" ng-model="credentials.email">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Password</span>
      <input type="password" ng-model="credentials.password">
    </label>
    <label class="item">
      <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Factory:

```
.factory('Somepost', function ($http) {
  return{
doPost: function (credentials, callback) {
  console.log('service');
  console.log(credentials);
  return $http({
    url:'http://cronicls.ru/auth/login',
    method: 'POST',
    data: credentials,
    async : true
  }).success(callback);
}}})
```

Login function in controller:

```
$scope.doLogin = function(credentials) {
  var successCallback = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
  Somepost.doPost(credentials, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

Function doLogin with $.ajax (working successfully):

```
$scope.doLogin = function(credentials) {
  var successCallback = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
  var login = function(credentials, successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'http://cronicls.ru/auth/login',
      async : true,
      data: credentials,
      success: function(data){
        console.log('login success');
        console.log(data);
        successCallback();
      },
      error: function(data){
        console.log('/auth/login: error');
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
   };
   login(credentials, successCallback);
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the two different server response? We do not know what you ar calling "wrong response". And would be good if you provide the HTTP calls as well. Just put what data are you posting in both calls, so we can compare the call and the response. For me, everything is ok with your code.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu yes. It's PHP with ZF on server side.

Comment: can you add this code to your server preferably in the begining just as a test? `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);`
                    `$_REQUEST = $_POST;`

Comment: @vinagreti 
successfull response: null{"result":"OK","user":{"id":"30","email":"leshazotov@gmail.com","password":null,"isConfirmed":"1","checkSum":null,"avatarPath":"\/uploads\/avatars\/Me_in_glasses.jpg","firstname":"\u0410\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0435\u0439","lastname":"\u0417\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0432","friends":[],"isFriend":false,"isMe":false,"notifyCount":"3"}}

unsuccessful: Object {result: "ERROR", msg: "invalid values"}

Comment: Your response seems to be ok. Now we need to check the requests. I think you are passing different data on each request. When you are using JQuery, you call on a way and when you are using angular you call in another way. Check how you are passing your data. Check if is the same data that is being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of my problem. Thanks to @Jai for hint about ZF. Actually we need to wrap data in $.param(). So, working factory is:

```
.factory('Somepost', function ($http) {
  return{
    doPost: function (credentials, callback) {
      return $http({
        url:'http://cronicls.ru/auth/login',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $.param(credentials),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
     }).then(callback);
   }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

*but in response i have log from server, that values are wrong.*

Actually not, because it returns a promise and you have to do something like this in your callback:

As per your comment :

*It's PHP with ZF* on server side. Actually you need to change the default content Type header from `application/json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Change in factory:

```
.factory('Somepost', function ($http) {
  return{
    doPost: function (credentials, callback) {
    console.log('service');
    console.log(credentials);
    return $http({
      url:'http://cronicls.ru/auth/login',
      method: 'POST',
      data: credentials,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, // <-- override the default contentType header
      async : true
    }).then(callback); // change to then instead of success
}}})
```

Comment: I tried way, that you offer, but it's not working too. Thank you

Comment: Your comment _It's PHP with ZF on server side._ Actually you need to Either change your code to accept the posted data with `php://inputs` or you have to override the headers from the `http` request to use `form-url-encoded` format instead of `application/json` which is default header set in angular.